# Transaction not working in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I have a transaction to check if an entry in my table has the same date and `subHistoryID`. Regardless if the data matches or not the transaction always rolls back. Any help on this matter would be great.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]
    INSERT INTO History(Name, subHistoryID, GarageID, StaffID, Date, Notes)
    VALUES (@name, @subhistoryid, @garageid, @staffid, @date, @notes);

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM History 
               WHERE History.Date = @date AND History.subHistoryID = @subhistoryid) 
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1]
        PRINT 'ERROR: Rolling back transaction.'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'PASS: Committing transaction.'
        COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1]
    END
GO
```

[My data before attempting the transaction.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hli7u.png)

```
DECLARE @name varchar(20) = NULL;
DECLARE @subhistoryid int = 1;
DECLARE @garageid int = 1;
DECLARE @staffid int = 1;
DECLARE @date Date = '2018-10-21';
DECLARE @notes varchar(100) = 'test';
```

This data should roll back, which is does.

```
DECLARE @name varchar(20) = NULL;
DECLARE @subhistoryid int = 1;
DECLARE @garageid int = 1;
DECLARE @staffid int = 1;
DECLARE @date Date = '2016-1-1';
DECLARE @notes varchar(100) = 'test';
```

This data should commit, but it rolls back

Comment: You are checking after you insert, so, the exists condition will always be true.

Comment: You insert the new data first and then you check if it exists (of course it does, you just inserted it). Check first and if it doesn't exist, Insert (or use a Merge instead)

Comment: Ahh I see. A slight over look. Thanks

Comment: Assuming there is an `identity` column in your table you could capture the value of [`Scope_Identity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) after the `insert` and then check for `... where IdColumn != @NewIdValue and ...` so that the new row is ignored.